# El significado de "buti" en "cebolla buti"

Tags: significado, comida, nombres-propios

¿Qué significa "buti" en "[cebolla buti](https://www.efectofruta.com/products/cebolla-buti-6347.aspx)"? ¿Puede que se refiere al color de la cebolla? ¡Muchaas gracias!

Comment: Tiene la pinta de ser el formato, que es visualmente parecido a algo embutido.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se refiere al formato de presentación. En este caso, se llama así a la cebolla en malla.

Leído en
https://www.grupolomar.es/productos/cebolla-grano/.

Comment: Una aclaración para los que no somos españoles. "Butis de cebolla" o "cebolla en buti" se debe a un acortamiento de la palabra "butifarra", que se refiere a un tipo de embutido de forma alargada y también, como metáfora, a una "media" o "calza".